# Automating Firefox or Google Chrome

Tags: browser, automation, autohotkey, autoit

I have seen information about using AutoHotkey with Internet Explorer for form filling through COM interface.

Is there any possibility to do this using Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Some things Can be done but not like COM and IE, so i'd say look in to javascript if you realy need to work with the other browsers

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954282/autoit-with-firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is tagged AutoIt, so here's an AutoIt answer:

AutoIt does have a [UDF for firefox automation](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0600b/) that would do it. It's not a standard UDF and relies on a third party program.

Chrome has no interface for automation. In theory you could write a program that used webkit directly, and maybe even set the user agent to look like chrome. In practice I haven't seen it done, and it really is overkill when IE is a much easier choice for automation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)

Puppeteer is a Node.js library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome/Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs in headless mode by default, but can be configured to run in full ("headful") Chrome/Chromium.

What can it do?

Most things that you can do manually in the browser can be done using Puppeteer! Here are a few examples to get you started:

- Generate screenshots and PDFs of pages.
- Crawl a SPA (Single-Page Application) and generate pre-rendered
  content (i.e. "SSR" (Server-Side Rendering)).
- Automate form submission, UI testing, keyboard input, etc.
- Create an automated testing environment using the latest JavaScript
  and browser features.
- Capture a timeline trace of your site to help diagnose performance
  issues.
- Test Chrome Extensions.